# speed up matrices multiplication of different type using numba

Tags: numba, jit, typing

I'm trying to implement this code with numba, but don't understand why it's not compiling in nopython mode.

```
def mult(x,y):
    ran = len(x)
    for i in range(ran):
        y[i,:] = x[i]*y[i,:]
    return y
```

The error is:
typing error non-precise type pyobject

x is a matrix of form (n) and y (n,m) with dtype 'f4'.

Comment: The problem comes from the input type and you do not provide a *precise* input type. "x is a matrix" is vague. Please give an example (ie. python code) of `x` and `y` value causing the issue.

Comment: The dtype of both matrices is 'f4'. The data is read from .fits files.

Comment: The error is the same as if the matrices were defined as follows:
y = np.random.rand(1000,600)
x = np.random.rand(1000)

Comment: I got no issue with `y = np.random.rand(1000,600); x = np.random.rand(1000); mult(x,y)` and the decorator `@nb.njit`. Using `np.float32` also works. Thus, I cannot reproduce the problem. The error point out that you provide python object to the function and not Numpy arrays. Thus, I think you do something in your code that is not reported here (or maybe you use a very very old version of Numba).

Comment: Solved it by explicitly set the type to 'float32'. Nonetheless shouldn't be 'f4' = 'float32'?

Comment: It should regarding [the documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html). And again, I cannot *reproduce* the problem with f4 too... This is why providing [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is important.